# Bukkit trim not working

Tags: java, bukkit

For some odd reason when I try to trim "replace:" it doesn't get trimmed for some odd reason. Like part of it gets trimmed depending on how many characters that blacklisted word has but overall it's not working as expected.

Whats its suppose to do is replace "replace:" with "" but that doesn't want to work.

Heres my code:

@EventHandler
public void BlackListWords(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
    String labels = "replace:";

```
for (String s : p.file.getFile().getStringList(p.file.path + ".BlacklistedWords")) {
    String[] parts = labels.split(" ");

        String replace = parts[0];


        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Words:\n" + s.replace("replace:", ""));
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "StringList:\n" + s.split(" ")[0]);

        if (e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(s.split(" ")[0])) {
            e.setMessage(s.substring(replace.length()).replaceAll("//replace", "").split(" ")[0].replace("_", " "));
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing as to your intent, but I am assuming you are trying to take entries in the .BlacklistedWords file and remove all instances of them from e.getMessage()?  Are you simply trying to take them out of the message itself or are you trying to substitute replacements?  What is the format of the entries in your .BladklistedWords file, is it "replace: badword"?

Comment: @Michael, i'm trying to substitute the replacement. Any when I try to do that, the replace: is there

Comment: see my answer below, it deals with removing the "replace:" also your code above is calling set message using s as the parameter, where s is the line you read from the blacklist, not the message itself.  In the example below incomingMessage would be your e.getMessage() and modifiedMessage would be what you would use as the value in e.setMessage()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that may help.  Reading your code it appears that your string list from the file probably has lines that have "replace: " as a prefix on them, and then you are doing several redundant things to try and remove that prefix before ultimately using the wrong string as your message.  See if this helps to clarify, but it is based on what I am assuming you are trying to do...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.Test;

public class StackOverflow_32878663 {

    @Test
    public void replaceBlacklistedWords()
    {

        // mimicking your list of strings from the file
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        wordList.add("replace: blue");
        wordList.add("replace: green");
        wordList.add("replace: red");
        wordList.add("replace: white");
        wordList.add("replace: yellow");

        String incomingMessage = "I am RED, white, bLuE, and green all over.  What am I?";
        String modifiedMessage = incomingMessage;

        for (String s : wordList)
        {
            // one way of many to remove "replace:" if that is important
            String justTheWord = s.split(" ", 2)[1];  

            // the (?i) tells the regex to perform in a case insensitive manner
            modifiedMessage = modifiedMessage.replaceAll("(?i)" + justTheWord, " ");  
        }

        System.out.println("Original message: " + incomingMessage);
        System.out.println("Modified message: " + modifiedMessage);
    }

}
```